# ComputerCraft/BigReactors Energy Security System

Tags: lua, comparison, computercraft

I'm making a ComputerCraft program for the Big Reactors mod to make sure that I never run out of power. When I execute my program, I get an error: `startup:7: attempt to compare __lt on nil and number`. Here is my code:

```lua
reactor = peripheral.wrap("back")

    while getEnergyStored < 1000 do
        reactor.setActive = true

    while getEnergyStored > 9999999 do
         reactor.setActive = false
    end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not a place for Minecraft questions. This question is off-topic. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to see what type of questions are on topic for this site. Welcome to SO.

Comment: @HCBPshenanigans In my opinion this question is On-Topic! He don't ask about Minecraft. Even if his question is bad 'cause you can clearly see that he don't know what he does it's still On-Topic 'cause he askes about a problem with the scripting language Lua

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that `getEnergyStored` is not a number and cannot be compared using `>` with `1000`.

I went to check the [Big Reactors reference page](http://wiki.technicpack.net/Reactor_Computer_Port) and I think you are trying to use the function `getEnergyStored`. To do that, change it to `getEnergyStored()`.

You need the two parentheses to tell the program to call the function instead of passing it as a variable.

Secondly, the program will not recognise `getStoredEnergy()` alone, because such a function belongs to your `reactor` variable.

Thirdly, `setActive` cannot be assigned to, it is a function. Call it like this: `setActive(state)` where state is either `true` or `false`.

I've rewritten your code to make it work

```
while true do
  --Get the stored energy count from the reactor
  local energy = reactor.getStoredEnergy()
  if energy < 1000 do
    reactor.setActive(true)
  else if energy > 9999999 do
    reactor.setActive(false)
  end
end
```